# How to convert json to object?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-3.6, jsonpickle

I need to convert a json-string to python object. By object I mean "new" python3 object like:

```
class MyClass(object):
```

I found several help for example on jsonpickle documentation. But all I found are tutorials which convert object to json first and after this convert backwards.

I want to convert a json-string from a [Rest-API](https://www.openligadb.de/api/getmatchdata/39738).

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import requests
import jsonpickle

class Goal(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.GoaldID = -1
        self.IsPenalty = False

class Match(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Goals = []

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}

url = "https://www.openligadb.de/api/getmatchdata/39738"

result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
obj = jsonpickle.decode(result.json)
print (obj)
```

This results in:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'method'
```

It's quite clear to me that jsonpickle can't convert this to my classes (Goal, Match), because I don't tell jsonpickle in which class the output should be converted. The problem is I don't know how to tell jsonpickle to convert the JSON in object from type Match? And how can I tell that the list of goals should be of type `List<Goal>`?

Comment: `obj = jsonpickle.decode(result.content)` => This will give you a dictionary.

Comment: `obj = result.json()` will also give you a dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following lines will give you a dictionary:

```
obj = jsonpickle.decode(result.content)  # NOTE: `.content`, not `.json`

obj = result.json()
```

But none of above will give you what you want (python object (not dicitonary)). because the json from the url is not encoded with `jsonpickle.encode` - whcih add additional information to a generated json (something like `{"py/object": "__main__.Goal", ....}`)

---

```
>>> import jsonpickle
>>> class Goal(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.GoaldID = -1
...         self.IsPenalty = False
...
>>> jsonpickle.encode(Goal())
'{"py/object": "__main__.Goal", "IsPenalty": false, "GoaldID": -1}'
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# JSON encoded with jsonpickle.encode  (default unpicklable=True)
#   => additional python class information attached
#   => can be decoded back to Python object
>>> jsonpickle.decode(jsonpickle.encode(Goal()))
<__main__.Goal object at 0x10af0e510>


>>> jsonpickle.encode(Goal(), unpicklable=False)
'{"IsPenalty": false, "GoaldID": -1}'
# with unpicklable=False   (similar output with json.dumps(..))
#   => no python class information attached
#   => cannot be decoded back to Python object, but a dict
>>> jsonpickle.decode(jsonpickle.encode(Goal(), unpicklable=False))
{'IsPenalty': False, 'GoaldID': -1}
```

---

If you want an actual Python object which is not a dictionary, i.e. you prefer `dic.Goals.[0].GoalGetterName` to `dic["Goals"][0]["GoalGetterName"]`, use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) with object_hook:

```
import json
import types    
import requests

url = "https://www.openligadb.de/api/getmatchdata/39738"

result = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(result.content, object_hook=lambda d: types.SimpleNamespace(**d))
# OR   data = result.json(object_hook=lambda d: types.SimpleNamespace(**d))
goal_getter = data.Goals[0].GoalGetterName
# You get `types.SimpleNamespace` objects in place of dictionaries
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Because I don't like the magic string access via dic, is it best practice to use a class method which converts a dic to an object?

Comment: @Sebi, Why do you convert the dict to an object? I just used the dictionary/list/... without converting when I was using Python. (I don't think it's a magic string access ;;;)

Comment: @Sebi, I didn't use this, but check this out: http://jsonmodels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: It's because I just don't like the magic string access, for example: dic["Goals"][0]["GoalGetterName"], I would prefer match.goals[0].goalGetterName but maybe this needs to much afford.

Comment: @Sebi, if you don't want to define mapping, you can define custom [`JSONDecoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) which convert JSON object to [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) instead of Python dictionary.

Comment: @Sebi, BTW, `dic["Goals"][0]["GoalGetterName"]` has no magic. Just simple item accesses ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the stuff :) Now I will find a way. JSONModels look nice. What I mean by magic string is a hardcoded string like "Goals", which I don't because it isn't able to refactor this and so on...But I'm from C# maybe I'm just not familiar enough with this dynamic stuff ;)

Comment: @Sebi, Maybe using `json.loads` with `object_hook` is more appropriate for your case.

Comment: @Sebi, I updated the answer to include an example with `json.loads(..., object_hook=...)`

Comment: Thank you very much. Would give +2 if possible :-D. This helped me alot.

Comment: @Sebi, No problem. Happy Python hacking!

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import json

class JsonObject(object):   

    def __init__(self, json_content):
        data = json.loads(json_content)
        for key, value in data.items():
            self.__dict__[key] = value      


jo = JsonObject("{\"key1\":1234,\"key2\":\"Hello World\"}")
print(jo.key1)
```

which prints:

```
1234
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

Answer (score 1):

A clean approach on recent python versions might be to use [marshmallow-dataclass](https://github.com/lovasoa/marshmallow_dataclass) :

```
from dataclasses import field
from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass 
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Goal:
    GoaldID: int = field(default=-1)
    IsPenalty: bool = field(default=False)


@dataclass
class Match:
    Goals: List[Goal] = field(default_factory=lambda: [])

my_match, _ = Match.Schema().load(result.json())
```